# Does the Levi-Civita symbol $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ really transform?

Tags: tensor-calculus, vectors, rotation

Since the Levi-Civita symbol is independent of coordinates, I wonder how can it transform as $\varepsilon^\prime_{lmn}=A_{il}A_{jm}A_{kn} \varepsilon_{ijk}$ under an orthogonal transformation $A$? Instead of looking at how $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ transforms, it is not more sensible to look at how $(\vec{A}\times \vec{B})_i=\varepsilon_{ijk}A_jB_k$ transforms?

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Determinants) answer your question?

Comment: @jacob1729 What do you want me to see there?

Comment: Under your proposed transformation scheme, the RHS is precisely the formula for the determinant. The RHS is thus $\det(A) \epsilon_{lmn}$ which is the statement that the $\epsilon$ symbol is in fact only an $SO(3)$ scalar. For all other transformations it picks up a determinant.

Comment: The determinant for orthogonal transformations is $\pm 1$. The symbol is a pseudotensor.

Comment: And, as the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Properties) explains, “Under the ordinary transformation rules for tensors the Levi-Civita symbol is unchanged under pure rotations, consistent with that it is (by definition) the same in all coordinate systems related by orthogonal transformations.” In short, pure rotations transform it into itself.